# Setting TreeViewNode to selected on PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a tree view that I'm dynamically loading on the PageLoad event. Here is my tree view and data source:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tv" runat="server" DataSourceID="xds"
    SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="Red" NodeStyle-ForeColor="Black">   
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Node"
            ValueField="Id" TextField="Title"  />
    </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xds" runat="server" EnableCaching="false" />
```

This is the code I run on PageLoad

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb);

WriteTreeViewXml(xw);
xw.Flush();
xw.Close();

xds.Data = sb.ToString();
xds.DataBind();

tv.Nodes[0].Selected = true;  // error here
```

This works fine, the tree view gets loaded correctly. Now I'm trying to add styling to the SelectedNode. This works when I click on a specific node, but the root node isn't styled when the page loads. So I'm trying to set the root node to selected on PageLoad

I get this error when I try to set the root node as selected:

> **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index**

For some reason the tree view is empty after I bind the data source.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call tv.Databind() after the line that calls xds.DataBind();  Otherwise the control isn't being bound to the datasource. I believe it would do this for you if you were declaratively setting the XmlDataSource (to a static file, for example), but since you are manually populating it, you'll need to manually call the control's DataBind method as well.

Answer (score 1):

The data doesn't exist until the control's `DataBinding` event has been run, which may or may not happen during the `Load` event.  You should put any code which requires the data/nodes to exist into the `DataBound` event for the control.  See [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls):

> DataBound
>
> Raised at the end of data-binding operations in a data-bound control. In a GridView control, data binding is complete for all rows and any child controls.
>
> Use this event to format data-bound content or to initiate data binding in other controls that depend on values from the current control's content. (For more information, see Catch-Up Events for Added Controls earlier in this topic.)